# How to fix 'SQLSTATE[42S01]:base table or view already exists' error in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, migration

When I migrate the file then it shows me a this error (image link given).I've tried migrate:rollback ,migrate:refresh but it didn't work.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUf4A.png

> > Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table seed.#sql-16d8_15 (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table posts add constraint posts_user_id_foreign foreign key (user_id) references users (id) on delete cascade)

Comment: Please avoid posting source code or console output as image, it is better to paste it directly in your question.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/npfO1n5.png plaese have a look this image

Comment: Please have a look at the help section: [DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `seed`.`#sql-16d8_15` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `posts` add constraint `posts_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: You can just add it to your post by using the "edit" button

Answer (score 1):

Just manually delete the table

or run `php artisan migrate:fresh`